# T-SQL BETWEEN problem max value first

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Why this two expressions return different results? This is really stupid.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID BETWEEN 3 AND 1

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) says:

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than
>   or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to
>   the value of end_expression.

Doesn't say anything about swapping the start_expression and end_expression to match min and max values. You should expect the result as documented, not as you believe it should.

For the curious out there, the ANSI SQL99 standard specifies that the BETWEEN predicate should include a clause for SYMMETRIC or ASYMMETRIC comparison. Only the SYMMETRIC one is allowed to swap the start_range and end_range, the ASYMMETRIC one is required to be strict. The ASYMMETRIC form is the implicit form. In other words an implementation that interprets `A BETWEEN X and Y` as `(A>=X AND A<=Y) OR (A>=Y AND A<=X)`, as the OP suggests, is not standard compliant.

Comment: Strange, I remember like both are returning same results in MySQL. Just checked. Same in MySQL.

Comment: @Hasan Gürsoy MySQL is MySQL, not SQL Server. While it would be slightly interesting to see what the SQL specification said about BETWEEN, different databases need to be catered for as they may diverge greatly on either "interpretation" of the specification and/or may simply do their own thing -- MySQL quotes and NULL in SQL Server unique constraints come to mind. As such the appropriate *implementation* documentation needs to be consulted.

Answer (score 8):

`ID BETWEEN 3 AND 1` is simply short hand for `ID >= 3 AND ID <=1` so will never return any results.

If you look at the query plan you will see that the query text actually gets expanded out to this (**Edit** Or at least you can see this substitution of `BETWEEN` with `>=` / `<=` in queries that get auto parametrised)

Comment: SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [ID]>=@1 AND [ID]<=@2 why do we even use between for.

Comment: @Hasan - Saves typing the column name twice I suppose!